# apt-get update is throwing a error's and warnings

Tags: ubuntu, apt

when i run `sudo apt-get update` this is something i get

```
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://dl.bintray.com/apache/cassandra 311x InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F1000962B7F6840C
E: The repository 'http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list:1
```

and i'am unable to install anything now

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) went end of life in July 2019 and has been removed from the Ubuntu archive. By now it will have several serious security problems and you should upgrade to a supported release as soon as possible.

Unfortunately Ubuntu does not support upgrades from a non-LTS release like 18.10 to the next LTS, 20.04, so your only option may be to reinstall.

You may be able to limp along by replacing your mirror with:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

That could allow you to do a step-wise upgrade 18.10→19.04→19.10→20.04 to end up on a supported LTS release. Reinstall sounds quicker, though.

Comment: Probably best to stick with LTS versions